# Code coverage for Fitnesse

Tags: java, jenkins, tdd, code-coverage, fitnesse

I have just inherited a old java codebase (around 10 - 15 years old). It does not have any automated testing coverage, or at least the contemporary world knows about it. I am planning to write some Fitnesse scripts around it, to begin with.

I know about Concordion etc. And I have my reason to pick Fitnesse. I will keep away from that since that is not the topic of this question.

My question is, I don't know of a quick way to measure the code coverage done by the Fitnesse tests as I write them. I know that jacoco (or similar libraries) should be able to report them but I just can't figure out exactly how.

So, if anyone of you have worked on Fitnesse test scripts and have managed to have Jenkins report on the coverage achieved by the scripts, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself, because I tend to use FitNesse to test deployed applications (and I cannot measure code coverage in the 'real installation'). But I believe this should be fairly straightforward if you run your FitNesse tests as part of a Jenkins (or any other build server's) jUnit run, which measures code coverage.

To have your FitNesse tests be executed as part of a jUnit run: create a Java class annotated with @RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class) and give it a @Suite("MyPageOrSuite.That.IWantToRun") annotation to indicate which tests to run. This will execute the specified page(s) in the same Java process that the jUnit process is using, so if that is instrumented in some way to determine code coverage the coverage of your FitNesse tests will be included in the report.

[Sample jUnit test class](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/test/fitnesse/junit/FitNesseRunnerTest.java), running FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable:

```
@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir(".")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("../target/fitnesse-results")
public class FitNesseRunnerTest {
}
```